# Set space after inline code environment which ends with a space in comments

Tags: support, comments, markdown, code-formatting, whitespace

When writing comments, it is possible to write a space after the last character of the code so that it looks like `A:<space>`. When writing it within a question, however, it does not work.

But there is another problem which occurs when writing something like this in comments. There, it will look like `A:<space><end of inline code><no space although " " was written><normal text>` Note that there is no normal space between the space written within the inline code environment and the ongoing normal text. I would like to have a normal space after the end of the code block, too.

[Markdown code snippets don't allow trailing spaces](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/123584/372092) only answers one part of the problem: Inline code in a question. `<code>&lt;a&nbsp;</code>` produces `<a`  and there is a space behind `<a`  if it is set.

For comments, however, `<code>&lt;a&nbsp;</code>` does not work. Using the `NO-BREAK-SPACE` as suggested in [this answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/123592/372092) to this question does not work either.

Comment: For me to have voted for this to be re-opened I would want to see the "solved" part of the question removed/downplayed so that the question becomes clearly focused on the single question that you still wish to ask (and have answered).

Comment: There's proof the duplicate [working here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/306025/179419). Don't use `&nbsp;` put in the literal string (non-breaking space) instead. `a `bc

Comment: Proof moved to [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/306025/179419) after answers from the sandbox were archived.